# List as argument in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, return, arguments

I am confused as to why the following code is not working. My confusion lies with the returns and prints. I don't know how to make the list as the argument.  Everything else seems to work fine up until that part.

```
def while_mean(l):
  sum = 0
  length = float(len(l))
  index = 0 
  while index < len(l):
    sum = l[index] + sum
    index = index + 1
  return sum/length

def for_mean(l):
  sum = 0
  length = float(len(l))
  for i in l:
    sum = i + sum
    mean = sum/length
  return mean

def stats():
  apd = ([])
  nume = input("write a number:")
  while nume != 'n':
    apd.append(nume)
    print apd
    nume = input("write another number:")
  return sum(apd)
  return while_mean([apd]) 

print stats()
print while_mean([apd])
```

---

changed def stats to:

```
def stats():
  apd = ([])
  nume = raw_input("write a number:")

  while nume != 'n':
    apd.append(float(nume))
    print apd
    nume = raw_input("write another number:")

  return sum(apd)

print apd = ([])
print stats()
print while_mean(apd)
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? What about making the "list as an argument" do you need help with?

Comment: Using `l` as an identifier is bad practice. It looks so much like `1` that you are setting yourself up for difficult debugging problems sooner or later. Also, note that `[apd]` is a list of lists rather than a list of numbers. Why are you wrapping `apd` (which is already a list) in a list?

Comment: I modified my code, and the reason why I need to use 'n' instead of -1, is because my teacher said so :/.  My specific problem here is that my list apd won't be seen as a variable when I try to put it in my argument for my while_mean() call.  And I said 'list as an argument' because I didn't know if using a list as an argument was an issue or not.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return twice, so only the first of these two will run

```
return sum(apd)
return while_mean([apd])
```

`apd` is only defined inside the `stats` function, so if you want to use it outside then define it before running the function or return it.

Also, if you intend `apd` to be a list then don't call it like `while_mean([apd])` but rather

```
while_mean(apd)
```

otherwise you create a list of list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def while_mean(l):
    sum = 0
    length = float(len(l))
    index = 0 
    while index < len(l):
        sum = l[index] + sum
        index = index + 1
    return sum/length

def for_mean(l):
    sum = 0
    length = float(len(l))
    for i in l:
        sum = i + sum
        mean = sum/length
    return mean

def stats():
    nume = input("write a number:")
    while nume != -1:
        apd.append(nume)
        print apd
        nume = input("write another number:")
    return sum(apd)
    return while_mean([apd]) 

apd = ([])
print stats()
print while_mean(apd)
```

With the way that your code was, you were declaring the `apd` variable inside of the `stats` function, but it is better to declare that variable outside of the function, and then pass it into the function as a parameter, so that the current list is maintained outside of the function.
If you do this you can also pass the `apd` variable to the `while_mean` function.

Another thing, is in the `stats()` function, it is better to compare the value of `nume` to `-1` (or any other number you would like) as opposed to a character for the condition of the while loop.
This is because `nume` is assigned to be an `integer`, when an integer is entered.  So, `nume` is of the type `integer`, and because `nume` is of the type `integer`, you cannot then enter a character, and have a character assigned to the variable `nume`.

With this solution you would enter `-1` when you are done entering numbers to put in the list.

I have modified your code, and the revisions that I made are above. I hope this helps.

Comment: but then I'm dividing by 0 because that specific apd (defined after the function) has a length of 0, so it wouldn't work